# can't create a symfony 4 project with "symfony/website-skeleton"

Tags: symfony4

I have an error message when I create the project with --full

Symfony CLI version v4.21.3 (2020-12-11T09:19:56+0000 - stable)

PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2017 18:34:46) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Composer version 2.0.8 2020-12-03 17:20:38

And command using

```
symfony new blog --full
```

error message

```
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!
!!   // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
!!
!!  07:21:01 CRITICAL  [php] Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Twig\Environment::registerUndefinedTokenParserCallback() ["exception" => Error { …}]
!!
!!  In srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php line 1546:
!!
!!    Attempted to call an undefined method named "registerUndefinedTokenParserCallback" of class "Twig\Environment".
!!    Did you mean to call e.g. "registerUndefinedFilterCallback" or "registerUndefinedFunctionCallback"?
!!
!!
!!  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcdrI.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form

Comment: Thanks for adding the error message. Please share more details, like: which command are you using? Which PHP version? Which package versions?

Comment: It's done, like the error message in text form

Comment: What do you mean by "done"? I cannot see any of the requested information in the question

Comment: it's good now ?

Comment: Thanks - that looks like a bug to me, I'll have a look about how to report it

Comment: See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/39734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in `twig/extra-bundle` v3.2.0, according to [my bug report](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/39734). The broken version was unpublished, and starting a project is possible again using PHP 7.1

Comment: i need to update ```twig/extra-bundle``` or php?

Comment: Neither - simply run that command `symfony new blog --full` once more